# How to set required field to not required in angular controller after the form passed to controller

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I have set `ng-required="valid"` to `true` in controller and In html after passing  form from the click event (ex :saveData(form)) in the `saveData()` method based on condition i set `$scope.valid= false` and need to check the `form.$valid`.

However setting `$scope.valid = false`, does not modify the form `ng-required` attributes i have settled to  `true` initially.

```
<form name="customForm" noValidate>
    <input type="text" ng-required="valid"/>
    <button ng-click ="saveData(customForm)"></button>
</form>
```

### in Controller

```
$scope.valid = true;

$scope.saveData = function(form){
  $scope.valid = false;
  if(form.$valid){
   // ng-required values set to false and take action
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass 'customForm' to your function. Just declare it in controller.
I also don't understand why you need 'valid' variable.
Check that working sample:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="addCtrl">
    <form id="extra-pin" ng-submit="saveData()" name="customForm">
        <input type="text" ng-required="valid" name="test" id="test" 
                    ng-model="test"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('addCtrl', ['$scope' ,function($scope) {
    console.log($scope.customForm);

    $scope.customForm = null;
    $scope.valid = true;

    $scope.saveData = function(){
        //$scope.valid = false;
        //console.log($scope.customForm);

        if($scope.customForm.$valid){
        console.log($scope.customForm);
           // // ng-required values set to false and take action
        }
    }
}]);
```

[link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82L0cegw/8/)

Comment: hi, for an odd requirement ,when user comes to this form  initially from another i need to set ng-required values to true and display error.but when submitting the form i need to clear those fields  and also the form with these fields as not required.

Comment: depending on one condition only i need to pass these all required fields to back-end.  otherwise i need  above modification.

Comment: I haven't completely understand your case. If you uncomment that line from my sample : '//$scope.valid = false;' isn't that what you need?

Comment: yeah.but it does it update form validity?($scope.customForm.$valid) to true ? that doesn't happen. that's the issue.

Comment: As I see from my console it does update the validity '$valid: true'

Comment: scenario i worked with is set ng-required to field and give empty value.inside onSave set valid property to false.(so field not required now) then check form validity i expect it to be true, but getting false.

Comment: This is not a correct angular approach but if you want add this line before $valid check and it will play with your scenario : '$scope.customForm['test'].$setValidity('required', true);'

Comment: thanks.. yes for this scenario have to use custom modification.above solution works..